# Questions about building software

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I recently asked the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14092716/build-tor-on-diskstation on Stackoverflow about building from source because I got an error I could not fix. The question was closed as off-topic.

So my question here is: Is building not a part of software development? Where should I ask such questions?

(It would also be nice if a close-vote was accompanied by a comment explaining the reason a bit more detailed.)

Comment: I feel this comes closer to application support than actual development. Perhaps Super User welcomes a question like that? Check though, I don't participate there.

Comment: It's not really a question about building software...it's a question about an error message outputted by a build-script, and the error message describes that something on your system is not working correctly...shot in the dark, did you also install OpenSSL (and not only the dev package)? Also, one way or the other, the question sounds like a really, really, really oddcase and can most likely be closed as "too localized".

Answer (score 2):

I can not exactly answer why your question is off topic. How ever I can answer you what contributes your question get closed. As per the fundamental rule of SE is *"Questions that are not a good fit for this site may be voted closed by experienced community members."*. Now the question is what makes your question not a good fit for the site

- Your question is very vague and too open. You described issue and asking help. Not asking specific question. SE is Question and answer site where you post constructive questions and invite answers for those question. Here what is your specific question? "*can any body help"* is not constructive question.
- Your question is not showing any research effort. For any question that you want help from the community, first do your research and document that research.

Above are the basic things that makes your question not fit into SE. First you fix the above things in your question. Try to do research or Google why that error is coming and how can you fix that. Try to trouble shoot based on your research. If you have still problem then modify your question by specifying what ever research that you have done and ask the specific question. The question would be like the below

> I am trying to build application A on platform P as per the specified build process. How ever I am getting the below exception.
>      *Exception message*
>   I have done following things to trouble shoot and get rid of that exception.
>      *Explain the research that you have done and trouble shoot that you did*
>   No my specific question is, why this error occurring and how to over come this error in order to build application successfully

The above pattern will make your question better than now.

And you modify your question then you can request members who voted for close. Then there are chances that your question gets reopened. Or if they see any other problems with your question they will let you know.

Comment: Hmm, I think I wrote nearly all that you suggested (software, platform, error message) in my original question. Just in other words. The only thing that´s missing is the documentation of my research. Of course I asked search engines first. But beyond that I had no idea what to do...

Comment: @JanStrube: Your question is also vague. You should present in different words.

Comment: I "fixed" my question.

Comment: Thanks, but I´m giving up. Editing my question didn´t help and no one let me know, what the problem is...

Comment: @JanStrube: Try to request members who voted for close through comments section using at-username pattern. They will definitely let you know the reason.